# "Equals" - a verb or not?

Tags: parts-of-speech

I was checking out the usage of the word "equal" as a verb on the Merriam-Webster website. Under the "Recent Examples on the Web: Verb" section, I stumbled upon this peculiar quotation:

"That map also showed that the regions of Tampa Bay, Daytona Beach and Palm Beach County stood as more or less equals as the nation’s champs of lightning."

Frankly speaking, "equals" in this quotation doesn't strike me as a verb, but rather as an adverb (stood how? - as equals). So, what is it? And if it's a verb, why then?

Comment: It's a noun as evident from the fact that it has a plural form "equal" ~ "equals".

Comment: It is a noun. Stood as friends. Stood as mates. Stood as brothers. Stood as equals. But that slot cannot take a verb. You can't say "Stood as goes, stood as thinks, stood as buys, stood as calculates".

Comment: @BillJ   "equals" is  both an adjective and  a verb in the third person singular.  Ending in "s" doesn't necessarily mean it's plural.  e.g. **It equals.**

Comment: @Centaurus True, but it does in the OP's example, where it is complement of the prep "as" - a role typically filled by an NP, in this case a plural one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Merriam-Webster definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equal#h3) for the verb *equal* is:

> **equal** verb
>   equaled *or* equalled; equaling *or* equalling
>
> **Definition of equal (Entry 3 of 3)**
>
> *transitive verb*
>   **1** : to be equal to
>   *especially* : to be identical in value to
>   **2** *archaic*: EQUALIZE
>   **3** : to make or produce something equal to

---

If you scroll down the page, you'll see the heading **Recent Examples on the Web: Adjective**.

Under that is a **See More (+)** link.

Click on that, and many examples of the verb *equal* will be seen—including the example in question:

> **Recent Examples on the Web: Verb**
>
> // My family would do occasional vacations and stay at hotels, so to me a hotel *equaled* a vacation; hotel stays were immeasurably fun as a result.
>   — Mark Ellwood, Condé Nast Traveler, "The Stories of IRL Eloise: People Who Live in Hotels," 30 Nov. 2018
>
> // The $345,300 Ferrari 488 Pista and $293,200 Porsche 911 GT2 RS *equal* its 0-60 mph time of 2.7 seconds.
>   — Basem Wasef, WIRED, "McLaren's $958,966 Senna Hypercar Ain't Pretty, but It Can Whip a Track," 30 June 2018
>
> // That map also showed that the regions of Tampa Bay, Daytona Beach and Palm Beach County stood as more or less *equals* as the nation’s champs of lightning.
>   — Kevin Spear, OrlandoSentinel.com, "Florida loses reign as lightning leader to Mississippi," 26 Jan. 2018

The first two examples above are clearly verbs. They describe the actions of one thing equalling another.

---

But in the example in question, *equals* is not actually being used as a verb.

When used as a verb, *equals* is used in the following manner:

> X equals Y.

But here is a simplified version of the example sentence in question:

> They stood as equals.

---

In fact, if you look at the heading **Recent Examples on the Web: Noun**, you'll see the following example:

> // In one oil sketch here, a trapper and Indian guide, the exhibition notes, appear as *equals* on horseback.
>   — Edward Rothstein, WSJ, "‘Albert Bierstadt: Witness to a Changing West’ Review: Where the Sublime Joins the Melancholy," 25 June 2018

This ***appear as equals*** construction mirrors the ***stood as equals*** construction from the example in dispute.

Since the same construction (both syntactical and semantic) can't be used for both functions of the word, the categorization of one of the two examples must be in error.

---

In short, Merriam-Webster made a mistake in including the example you raised in the section reserved for verb usage. It's being used as a noun and should have been put in the noun section instead.

---

As to your point about it being an adverb:

> "How did they stand?"
>   "They stood as equals."

Here, *as equals* is acting as an adverbial phrase, but the word *equals* is, itself, a noun.

Compare it to this:

> "How did they drink?"
>   "The drank like fish."

Here, *like fish* is also being used as an adverbial phrase, but the word *fish* is, itself, a noun.

Answer (score -1):

'***Equal***' is a noun.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:

***equal***
 noun

: one that is equal

// insists that women can be absolute ***equals*** with men
— Anne Bernays.

Comment: -1 [Here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equal#h3) is the Merriam-Webster definition of the *verb* form of equal. Your answer does nothing to directly address the question.